# Редактор pyqode перестал работать с PySide

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, pyside, pyqode

Раньше это работало, а некоторое времени спустя, при запуске начало вываливаться:

```
'PySide.QtGui.QScrollArea.setWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QScrollArea.setWidget(CodeEdit)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QScrollArea.setWidget(PySide.QtGui.QWidget)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Причина этой ошибки** оказалась довольно интересной – для этого нужно, чтобы вместе с `PySide` был установлен `PyQt4`.

`Pyqode` поддерживает 3 модуля для работы с `Qt`: `PyQt5`, `PyQt4` и `PySide`, И в таком же порядке он пытается их импортировать, пока не удастся хоть какой-то удачно импортировать.
Когда создавался редактор `pyqode`, первым был найден `PyQt4`, который когда-то поставил, и его обертка над `QPlainTextEdit` (`PyQt4.QtGui.QPlainTextEdit`) вызывалась и, оказалась несовместимой с PySide, из-за этого та ошибка и появлялась.

Догадался об причине ошибке, когда запустил этот код и увидел упоминание `PyQt4`:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getmro(type(self.code_editor)))
```

Вывелось:

```
(<class 'pyqode.core.api.code_edit.CodeEdit'>, 
 <class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QPlainTextEdit'>, 
 <class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QAbstractScrollArea'>, 
 <class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QFrame'>,
...
```

Для полной уверенности, удалил `PyQt4` и запустил снова – работает, ошибки нет.

---

**Что сделать чтобы было хорошо?**

Есть несколько вариантов:

- Использовать виртуальное окружение
- Не держать зоопарк модулей для работы с `Qt`
- Переписать проект на `PyQt5` – он первый в списке импорта (но надолго ли?)